# Error in scraping some url with Python request

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

I am new to python and requests. I am having the following error with some url but not others, can anybody help? Thanks!

What works:

```
import requests

res = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL?p=AAPL')
```

What does not work:

```
import requests

res = requests.get('https://volumebot.com/?s=aapl')
```

Error I am getting:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='volumebot.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /?s=aapl (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:645)'),))
```

Comment: I had some similar error due to my open ssl lib, could you try to run this `import ssl
print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)`

Comment: Hi Phung Duy Phong, thanks for commenting. Mine is: OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016. Would this cause the problem?

Comment: I actually not sure since my computer execute your code without a problem, worth a try,

Comment: Also if you update your open ssl ( I use pip to update it), mine is OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019, in the past I have problem with openssl around 1.0.2c, so if you update and get error, just downgrade it to different version and try

Answer (score 0):

When you try these requests in the browser, you'll notice that the request to volumebot sets a cookie with session information. It's quite possible that this is required for this service, while it is not required for the Yahoo one.